# How can I justify $g/l = 1$ in the simple pendulum equation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, units, oscillators, dimensional-analysis

The differential equation for a simple pendulum can be given as,

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\theta}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + \frac{g}{l}\sin\theta = 0$$

In some notes I found that $g/l$ can be assumed as $1$ (i.e $g/l = 1$) without loss of generality, and this can be rewritten as

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\theta}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + \sin\theta = 0$$

How is the assumption $g/l = 1$ justified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This all comes down to having the freedom to choose units for the quantities.

Recall that a physical quantity can be written as a product of a number and a unit. In this case, you have several examples of physical quantities: $\theta$, $g$, $l$, and $t$. For example, in the case of $l$, if the pendulum is $0.75\ \mathrm{m}$ long, the unit would be meters and the numerical value associated with that unit would be $0.75$. But you could just as well use a different unit, like centimeters, in which case the number is $75$ and the unit is $\mathrm{cm}$.

In abstract terms, we can represent the numerical value of a quantity like $l$ as $l_n$ (and similarly for the others), and the unit as $\hat{l}$. This means you would write
$$l = l_n \hat{l}$$
You could set $l_n = 0.75$ and $\hat{l} = \mathrm{m}$, or $l_n = 75$ and $\hat{l} = \mathrm{cm}$, or so on.

Now see what happens if I take the pendulum equation and do this for *time*. With a little algebra I can write it as
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\theta}{\mathrm{d}t_n^2} + \hat{t}^2\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta = 0$$
I've used the fact that $\hat{t}$ is a constant, so you can pull it out of the derivative. It's just the chain rule: when $u = ax$,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}u} = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}u}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{1}{a}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
Then since you can choose the units of a quantity to be whatever you want, you might as well choose $\sqrt{l/g}$ as the unit of time. That means that
$$\hat{t}^2\frac{g}{l} = \frac{l}{g}\frac{g}{l} = 1$$
and you're left with
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\theta}{\mathrm{d}t_n^2} + \sin\theta = 0$$
Note that $\sqrt{l/g}$ is related to the pendulum's period by $T = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}$. So the point is that, **if you measure time in units of $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ of the pendulum's own period** rather than in units of seconds or minutes or whatever, you can get rid of that $g/l$ factor.

Answer (score 3):

I think they're just choosing a time scale.  Note that the units of $\frac{g}{\ell}$ are $\left(\frac{\rm m}{\rm s^{2}}\right)\frac{1}{\rm m} = \frac{1}{\rm s^{2}}$.

So, if you replace the second with a unit of time equal to $\sqrt{\frac{\ell}{g}}$, then in that system of units, we have $\frac{g}{\ell} = 1$

Answer (score 2):

So you have some $\theta(t)$ satisfying $\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} + (g/\ell)\sin\theta = 0.$ Define $\varphi(\tau) = \theta(\tau~\sqrt{g/\ell})$ and notice that by the chain rule, $$\frac{d^2\varphi}{d \tau^2} = \frac g\ell \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2},$$and the $g/\ell$ divides away.